# scala autocomplete intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-scala

I have a strange behavior from intellij and scala. When I try to use auto completion it kind of only works for the suggestions not methods related. Once I type the first names method names it works as shown in the second picture. Any ideas how to fix it ?
I tried:

- reset the cache
- reload the project
- reinstall scala plugin

I'm using intellij Community 2019.2.2

Examples:
[image: int] 
[image]

Comment: Try this one remove .idea folder and re-open project

Comment: I've tried that to

Comment: Hi @JorgeMachado Can you add a screenshot of your Settings/Editor/General/Code Completion settings please. Also try to use sorting just to see if the result changes. It might be a setting causing this.